# Vista machine not broadcasting DHCP device name on network

Tags: windows-vista, dhcp, tcpip, ntlm

When I look on my router at 'attached devices' - I see the names of my XP machine and my Ubuntu box - but the Vista name is not there (despite seeing the IP addresses of all three connected - ie the Vista box shows as device name 'unknown'.)

DHCP is enabled on the Vista box - and the LmCompatibilityLevel is set to 1 and has been rebooted.

Any idea what could be causing this?

JG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this fixed it for me:
http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/vista-not-working-with-dhcp/

And changing this registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
EnablePlainTextPassword
```

to

```
1
```

(Although that second one indicates there is a problem with my Samba config.)

Thanks for your help.

JG

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Vista to be on a "private" network (as opposed to a "public") one? Have you enabled file and print sharing?

Or, if you want to get this up and running in a simple way, you can just disable Windows Firewall. It shouldn't matter much in a home LAN.